# Objective C - object allocating good practice

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, superclass

I'm trying to build MVC Application with Objective-C, I'm trying to allocate and init my model once in my superclass witch is UIViewController, my idea is to do it once in superclass and to have access from every subclass of my superclass.

**superclass.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Lecturer *lecturer;
```

**superclass.m**

```
 - (void) viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
 }

#pragma mark - GET

 - (Lecturer *)lecturer {
   if (!_lecturer) {
   _lecturer = [Lecturer alloc]init];
   }
   return _lecturer;
}
```

My idea is to call self.lecturer from all subclasses and set/get the lecturer class property's but every time when i call self.lecturer its creating a new instance, i know i can use **SINGLETONE** but is there any way i can do it differently without singletone design pattern?

Thanks for attention.

Comment: If you don't want to use a singleton dependency injection can do trick by passing the first instance of lecture to the other view controllers.


http://www.objc.io/issue-13/singletons.html

Answer (score 3):

How about using `static` variable?

```
- (Lecturer *)lecturer {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static Lecturer *o;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        o = [[Lecturer alloc] init];
    });
    return o;
}
```

In addition `dispatch_once` helps to do it thread-safely.

Comment: Yes, this works, but still the singletone do the same work, thank you for you answer.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't correctly understood what you meant.

From my experience, avoiding singleton pattern is a little troublesome in iOS app dev. In general, to share model objects, you can use singleton pattern or simply relay and propagate these to use-side objects (Views and Controllers). But iOS SDK's special features, storyboard for example, instantiate controller classes in self‐serving manner. So you'd have to learn how to pass model objects to view controllers for each case.

Comment: Well if i found a solution will post it :)